# checkbox to move an element from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I need to use a checkbox to remove a member from a group. Below is the copy of the data. Group is an array in the member object. This is the mentioned object's data-structure ...

```
[{
  // member item.
  created_at: "NA",
  email:"test@test.com",
  firstname: "molly",
  lastname: "jones",
  groups: [{
    // group association item.
    group_title:" title",
    group_id: 4,
    group_description: "description",
  }],
}, {
  // member item.
  created_at: "NA",
  email:"example@test.com",
  firstname: "tim",
  lastname: "smith",
  groups: [{
    // group association item.
    group_title:" test",
    group_id: 5,
    group_description: "example",
  }],
}]
```

I am using react and the checkbox is usually a boolean value. So I need to think of way to toggle the checkbox true false when clicked and remove the group_id from the array to remove the member from the group.

```
<Checkbox
     checked={isChecked } //I need a boolean value here. Maybe isChecked
     aria-label="member of the group"
     onChange={handleCheckboxToggled}/>

let isChecked = false

const handleCheckboxToggled = () => {
  memberData.forEach((memberInfo) => {
   if (memberInfo.group_id === groupId){
     //here I want to remove the group_id
     // have a new array without that group_id
     let isChecked = true
    } 
  }
}
```

Then I could filter or map through the member array and if the params (groupId) matches the group_id in the member object I could push the empty array with the group_id removed.  How do I remove the matching group id from the array and return the empty array?

Comment: How does your checkbox relate to the item in the array?

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: The right way to display the initial values for the checkboxes depends a lot on the code surrounding the checkbox.  Show us the loop which displays your checkboxes and the declaration of memberData (is it a state var?) and whatever list you have that contains all the possible groups.

Comment: This seems like a data modeling/UX problem. I mean, if unchecking the checkbox removes the item from the list, there will never be unchecked items in the list, so you don't need to model the case where isChecked = false. It also seems like a checkbox is an odd UI choice; I'd think a 'Delete' button would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question correctly, you can try this way

```
    const YourComponent = () => {
  const [memberData, setMemberData] = useState([
    {
      created_at: 'NA',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      firstname: 'molly',
      lastname: 'jones',
      groups: [
        {
          group_title: ' title',
          group_id: 4,
          group_description: 'description',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      created_at: 'NA',
      email: 'example@test.com',
      firstname: 'tim',
      lastname: 'smith',
      groups: [
        {
          group_title: ' test',
          group_id: 5,
          group_description: 'example',
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const groupId = 5;

  const handleCheckboxToggled = () => {
    setMemberData((prevMemberData) =>
      prevMemberData.map((memberInfo) => {
        if (memberInfo.groups.find((group) => group.group_id === groupId)) {
          return {
            ...memberInfo,
            groups: memberInfo.groups.filter((group) => group.group_id !== groupId),
          };
        }
        return memberInfo;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {memberData.map((member, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{member.email}</p>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            aria-label='member of the group'
            checked={member.groups.some((group) => group.group_id === groupId)}
            onChange={handleCheckboxToggled}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```